# Downloading an Excel file with plots and dataframes from shiny. (Not working for plots)

Tags: shiny

Hello fellow shiny users.

I am running across a problem I can't seem to find any solution to on the various forums and websites. 
I will share a relatively simple reproducible example that illustrates my problem.

I want to do the following: Upload some data, do some processing and analysis, then put the whole bunch of outputs into an Excel file and finally download it. 
I have no trouble creating that Excel in the shiny server part, and putting dataframes/tables into it. But I can't put images in the Excel file.

It is because the AddPicture function from the xlsx package I use requires the following things:

---

addPicture(file, sheet, scale=1, startRow=1, startColumn=1)

file
the absolute path to the image file.

sheet
a worksheet object as returned by createSheet or by subsetting getSheets. The picture will be added on this sheet at position startRow, startColumn.

"The absolute path to the image file" is the problem. I can't have an absolute path to the file, as when I execute a similar script with R. Or can I?

---

Here is some code that shows the error:

If you execute it as it stands, you will be able to download an Excel file with a dataframe in the first sheet no problem. (Because there is no absolute path needed, just a dataframe object)
The part with #  in the server part is what bring me problems. You can uncomment it to see the error (Error : no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "NULL" ) . Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

SERVER

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$download.Excel <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() { paste("Excelfile.xlsx")},

  content = function(file){
       example_plot=plot(1:10,1:10)
       Results_Workbook <- createWorkbook(type='xlsx')
       A=as.data.frame(matrix(2,2,2))
       sheet.1 <- createSheet(Results_Workbook, sheetName = "Data frame")
       addDataFrame(A, sheet=sheet.1, startRow=4, 
       startColumn=2,row.names=FALSE)
       setColumnWidth(sheet.1,colIndex=c(1:100),colWidth=30)
       sheet.2 <- createSheet(Results_Workbook, sheetName = "Plot")
       # ggsave("plot",example_plot, device="emf")
       # addImage(file = "plot.emf", sheet = sheet.2, scale = 55,
       #          startRow = 4, startColumn = 4)
       saveWorkbook(Results_Workbook,file)
  } 

)
}
```

UI

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Simple classification script with R/Shiny"),
      sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
             downloadButton('download.Excel', 'Download')

             ),
          mainPanel(p("Description of the results")
          )
     )
)
```

Best regards,

Joël

Comment: You can either have `ggsave` save to an absolute path, or use `getwd()` to get the current working directory and reconstruct the path (as `ggsave` saves to the current working directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working `server.R` file. Note that I couldn't get the emf file format to work, but jpeg works.

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$download.Excel <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() { paste("Excelfile.xlsx")},

    content = function(file){
      example_plot=qplot(1:10,1:10)
      Results_Workbook <- createWorkbook(type='xlsx')
      A=as.data.frame(matrix(2,2,2))
      sheet.1 <- createSheet(Results_Workbook, sheetName = "Data frame")
      addDataFrame(A, sheet=sheet.1, startRow=4, 
                   startColumn=2,row.names=FALSE)
      setColumnWidth(sheet.1,colIndex=c(1:100),colWidth=30)
      sheet.2 <- createSheet(Results_Workbook, sheetName = "Plot")
      ggsave("plot.jpeg",example_plot, device="jpeg")
      addPicture(file = paste0(getwd(), "/plot.jpeg"), sheet = sheet.2, scale = 1,startRow = 4, startColumn = 4)
      saveWorkbook(Results_Workbook,file)
    } 

  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. If you are ever interested in getting emf to work, there's a weird little trick that does it I think.

Comment: If you want to post the trick, that might help others in the future. Please also mark the answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: First of all, with ggsave(), I can't get it to work either.

Comment: Nevermind it probably does. 
But I know to for sure that with savePlot(), when saving the plot as an EMF I succedeed 

So basically, for me atleast when I only load the 'xlsx' library, imports of EMF files into the Excel will always fail. (png works for example though)
But when I load (in this order) 'XLConnect' and then 'xlsx' it works. Even though I only use the xlsx functions, loading XLConnect seems to help with the import of EMF files, for a reason that I don't know. (They both use Java stuff and might conflict/interact,I don't really understand)

Comment: You are correct! Loading `XLConnect` first will solve the issue with emf file for some strange reason.